# Is there equalvalent in C++- For a given seed, the order of the random numbers will always be the same

Tags: java, c++, random

If I have the following in Java...where I want to let the user specify the seed for the random number generator so for the given seed the order of the random numbers is always the same...eventually would enter the seed to generate the same letter pattern each time..

```
        Random rand = new Random(Long.parseLong(t[0])); 

       char r = (char)(rand.nextInt(26) + 'A');
        
What would be the equvalent to do the same for random in C++

cin >> seed;
srand(seed);
 char('A' + rand() % 26)
```

Would srand(seed) work in C++..I have seen responses go either way as in yes or no...

Comment: That Java Random always return the same numbers when using the same seed only works as long as all Java versions use the same algorithm for Random implementation. But that algo can be replaced at any time or in any Java distribution. Do not rely on it's deterministicallity! E.g. the SecureRandom implementation of Android was replaced some years ago and a lot of apps had problems with this. If you want a deterministic output use a standardized key generation function like PBKDF2.

Comment: Well, what's exactly stopping you from trying your `srand`-based approach, and see if it works as you expect?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there equalvalent in C++- For a given seed, the order of the random numbers will always be the same

Yes. This behaviour is inherent to all pseudo random number generators.

The C++ standard library has pseudo random number API in the `<random>` header. There's also the old C PRNG API, but I would recommend against using it for anything that requires decent quality randomness.

---

There is a caveat however. The sequence will be the same only as long as the PRNG algorithm remains the same. The algorithm of the old C API isn't specified exactly, and as such the sequence can - and does - vary across different standard library and/or language implementations. This problem applies to different implementations of the Java virtual machine as well.

The generator engines of the `<random>` API are specified exactly and are thus deterministic across implementations, except for the `std::default_random_engine` which can - and does - vary across implementations. Unfortunately, the distributions (uniform, normal etc.) of the standard API aren't specified exactly, so using them introduces potential variance across standard library implementations.

Comment: One solution is to write your own version of a simple PRNG and to use that.  Even just copy the implementation from one release so you can be sure it is always the same for your own program.